# Mule application blocked all of a sudden due to CORS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, mule

I have been playing with React, Node and Mule in order to make requests go through Mule. I managed to get it all working but today for some reason I get an ERROR:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:88/api/courses/pizza' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This ERROR was not there before, everything was perfectly working and it was returning JSON as it is supposed to. I reverted all changes I made but to no avail. I even used allow CORS extension for chrome but then it seemed like requests didn't even reach the Mule application executing in Anypoint Studio, since it returned no message. My Mule is on PORT 88, React 3000 and Node on 1234. I tried to use CORS interceptor in Anypoint Studio too according to this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/enable-cors-into-mule-4-at-application-level but that didn't help either. Please leave some advices as to what else I can try.

React request:

```
export default function APIRequest(url, method, body) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: body,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  });
}
```

Node:

```
router.get("/:name", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.name);
  const courses = await Course.find();
  course = courses.filter((course) => course.category === req.params.name);
  res.send(course);
});
```

Mule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:wsc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc/current/mule-wsc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_configuration" doc:name="HTTP_Listener_configuration" doc:id="70a95691-a977-48ff-8439-79a5d2fc7bb7" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="88" />
        <http:listener-interceptors >
            <http:cors-interceptor >
                <http:origins>
                </http:origins>
            </http:cors-interceptor>
        </http:listener-interceptors>
    </http:listener-config>
    <wsc:config name="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" doc:name="Web Service Consumer Config" doc:id="0a403287-6d01-45e1-bb5f-47ffcc7a5f71" >
        <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?wsdl" service="NumberConversion" port="NumberConversionSoap" address="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso">
            <wsc:web-service-security actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" />
        </wsc:connection>
    </wsc:config>
    <http:request-config name="First_REST_API" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="84f17cc0-eb86-4c2a-b122-7d5f22781423" basePath="https://random-data-api.com/api/number/random_number?size=1" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="93a99571-d4d7-43c3-9505-26f2a56e97b3">
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration1" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="282ae316-cee6-4305-ae58-283858258ec6">
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="random-data-api.com"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="Local_REST_API_Config" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="6cf97fb4-f770-44fb-b450-4ccccf29db1a" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="1234" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="0a9a912a-50df-4963-b17a-f61f53aaa656" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="3001" readTimeout="3000"/>
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="GET:\courses\id-find_course_by_id" doc:id="e4042d03-603f-41c5-91a1-e12c2992d75e" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener with URI ID" doc:id="b1ecf442-8975-4385-b11b-cac1677613ef" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" />
        <set-payload value="#[attributes.uriParams.id]" doc:name="Set payload with URI ID" doc:id="8499152a-c601-488c-8cbd-2a081e38b20f" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="REST API request for Course with ID" doc:id="d17382dd-e848-44fc-b4e4-495991b61325" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" outputMimeType="application/json">
            <http:body><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
            <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 id: payload
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
        <set-variable value='#[output application/json
&#10;---
&#10;{
&#10;   isPublished: payload.isPublished,
&#10;   tags: payload.tags map ( tag , indexOfTag ) -&gt; tag,
&#10;   "_id": payload."_id",
&#10;   dishName: payload.dishName,
&#10;   category: payload.category,
&#10;   author: payload.author,
&#10;   ingredients: payload.ingredients map ( ingredient , indexOfIngredient ) -&gt; {
&#10;       "_id": ingredient."_id",
&#10;       quantity: ingredient.quantity,
&#10;       unit: ingredient.unit,
&#10;       description: ingredient.description
&#10;   },
&#10;   cookingTime: payload.cookingTime,
&#10;   sourceUrl: payload.sourceUrl,
&#10;   imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
&#10;   price: payload.price,
&#10;   date: payload.date,
&#10;   "__v": payload."__v"
&#10;}]' doc:name="Set variable with response JSON" doc:id="f712c7d0-65a8-48ab-a7a4-088ba23c9956" variableName="results" mimeType="application/json" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Call REST API for random number" doc:id="90a7f6f5-aeba-4b28-a5af-43dcd4b87e16" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/api/number/random_number?size=1" />
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;---
&#10;payload.decimal]" doc:name="Set Variable with REST API response " doc:id="5e409a00-0968-4cc7-a24e-da4efb9b2e03" variableName="price_number"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform response to XML" doc:id="3a0f5690-a8ca-4e4d-9a8a-71645cf0940f" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[output application/xml
---
{
            NumberToDollars @(xmlns: "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"): {
                dNum: payload.decimal
}
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <wsc:consume operation="NumberToDollars" doc:name="Call SOAP API with payload for string version of number" doc:id="0a8622d2-98ab-4114-8902-57bcdc2f58ba" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" />
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;ns ns0 http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/
&#10;---
&#10;payload.body.ns0#NumberToDollarsResponse.ns0#NumberToDollarsResult]" doc:name="Set Variable with SOAP API response" doc:id="25495ffe-b5ef-49de-a9c0-d4db668a58a6" variableName="price_string"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform all responses into one JSON" doc:id="10c1c874-782b-4c4c-84d4-bb14bf3e50a7" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    isPublished: vars.results.isPublished,
    tags: vars.results.tags map ( tag , indexOfTag ) -> tag,
    "_id": vars.results."_id",
    dishName: vars.results.dishName,
    category: vars.results.category,
    author: vars.results.author,
    ingredients: vars.results.ingredients map ( ingredient , indexOfIngredient ) -> {
        "_id": ingredient."_id",
        quantity: ingredient.quantity,
        unit: ingredient.unit,
        description: ingredient.description
    },
    cookingTime: vars.results.cookingTime,
    sourceUrl: vars.results.sourceUrl,
    imageUrl: vars.results.imageUrl,
    price: vars.price_number[0],
    priceText: vars.price_string,   
    date: vars.results.date,
    "__v": vars.results."__v"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="GET:\courses\name-find_course_by_name" doc:id="11a73a6e-f58f-4c7d-b79a-a310f4e4dc8d" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener with URI name" doc:id="ee5e9716-60c1-41ae-9c12-dcd1b44cbb96" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/{name}" />
        <set-payload value="#[attributes.uriParams.name]" doc:name="Set payload with URI name" doc:id="bac678be-6661-42e7-ac54-db88dac44383" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="REST API request for Course with name" doc:id="9010ac49-c81f-4961-93f0-f0539494edb2" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/{name}" outputMimeType="application/json" >
            <http:body ><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
            <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 name: payload
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
    <flow name="GET:\courses-get_all_courses" doc:id="686d41ad-7d8b-40c6-9bb5-3e5ea53efd88" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="3dc9bfa3-eff1-4cfd-b931-8d47eeeb6695" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="REST API request for all courses" doc:id="c7ed66df-bb09-4ecd-9406-151dac1c1f30" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/" outputMimeType="application/json" >
            <http:body ><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
    <flow name="POST:\courses\post-create_course" doc:id="c1fd8373-a7e3-4b7d-bb5b-f3c8214c488b" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="18b0ed4d-5b6a-4d60-ba96-ed37d1ca10be" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/add/" />
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="REST API request for new course" doc:id="7b565a3e-8eef-4d3e-b3ab-113acca530ae" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/" outputMimeType="application/json" >
        </http:request>
    </flow>
    <flow name="DELETE:\courses\delete\id-delete_course" doc:id="3c8d98ce-89a7-4437-b9f4-3db38582e596" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener with URI ID" doc:id="77cfb541-b6e1-4d5d-a6e4-e66381b36af0" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/delete/{id}" />
        <set-payload value="#[attributes.uriParams.id]" doc:name="Set payload with URI ID" doc:id="663d6350-4921-40b2-b923-71a24bd46f2c" />
        <http:request method="DELETE" doc:name="REST API request for deleting course with ID" doc:id="6db59045-4d70-4901-b696-4f1068d7ef91" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/delete/{id}" outputMimeType="application/json" >
            <http:body ><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
            <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 id: payload
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
    <flow name="PUT:\courses\update\id-put_course" doc:id="42dc3b31-370b-4051-9799-0e957f2b1841" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener with URI ID" doc:id="9ca7c395-64c4-4c4c-a3b7-3e70323be279" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_configuration" path="/api/courses/update/{id}" />
        <set-variable value="#[attributes.uriParams.id]" doc:name="Set Variable with URI ID" doc:id="6677b155-ce84-445b-b608-bcd1f83c06b5" variableName="id" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="526b8602-25ae-4c47-949a-dd9bd1fe7c43" message="#[vars.id]"/>
        <http:request method="PUT" doc:name="REST API request for updating course with ID" doc:id="95024c7e-99df-4d2c-8ccd-5f2c9b09ca6a" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/update/{id}" outputMimeType="application/json" >
            <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 id: vars.id
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is a restriction on the browser, not on the Mule application. It looks like in the CORS interceptor configuration you didn't add either an authorized origin (looks to be 'http://localhost:3000' based on the error), or configure the resource as public. The first option is more secure because restricts to a limited lists of origins allowed to do the request. Those options are explained in the article you linked.